# $X$ Polish space. Homeomorphism between $X$ and subset of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: general-topology, borel-sets, polish-spaces

Let $X$ be a Polish space.
I already construct a homeomorphism between $X$ and a subset of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ by: Let $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ be a dense subset of $X$ and $x \mapsto (\min(1,d_X(x,x_n)))_n$.
I showed that f is uniformly continuous, $f:X \to f(X)$ is bijective and that $f^{-1}:f(X) \to X$ is continuous (could'nt  show uniformly for $f^{-1}$).
Now I want to follow that $f(X)\subset [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$  is  a complete subset.
Any ideas?

Comment: You won't be able to show that $f(X)$ is complete under these hypotheses. If it were, then it would be a closed subset of the compact space $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$, hence compact, and so $X$ would have to be compact as well, which it need not be.  What is true is that $f(X)$ is completely metrizable; ii.e. there is a compatible metric, possibly different from the metric inherited from $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$, under which it is complete.  And this is trivial - you know there exists a complete metric on $X$, so pull it back.

Comment: What do you have to show about $X$ or $f[X]$?; you already know by assumption it has a complete metric, right? So you have shown it's homeomorphic to a subset of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$. That's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if $f: X \to [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ is an embedding (i.e. $f:X \to f[X]$ is a homeomorphism) you cannot really do much anymore.

$f[X]$ will not be complete (in the metric inherited from the Hilbert/Tychonoff cube) in general:

> $f[X]$ is complete (in said metric) iff $f[X]$ is closed in $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ iff $f[X]$ is compact iff $X$ is compact.

If you know that $X$ is Polish, i.e. completely metrisable, a classical theorem tells us that $f[X]$ is a $G_\delta$ in $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$. That's all you can say about $f[X]$ in general.

Comment: That $f(X)$ is $\mathcal{G}_{\delta}$ follows from the fact, that $d(y_1,y_2) := d_X(f^{-1}(y_1),f^{-1}(y_2))$ (where $d_X$ is a complete metric for $X$) defines a complete metric for $f(X)$ that induces the relativ topology of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ for $f(X)$. Hence $f(X)$ is a Polish subspace of $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$  and so is a $\mathcal{G}_{\delta}$ in  $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ (proposition from Mazurkiewicz). Is this right?

Comment: @chrisMainly Yes, that would work if you already knew that theorem.